# Proper Handling of NoSuchElementException in foreach loops?

Tags: java, iterator, loops

Why foreach loops do not take into consideration when an iterator raises NoSuchElementException and stop the loop from executing?

Let me explain.

Typically an iterator needs to provide two important methods: hasNext and next. The next method can raise NoSuchElementException if there are no more elements to iterate. The hasNext method is more like a syntactic suger just to make your code a bit better. The important method is really next and this is the method which should do any work, if at all, but not hasNext and it needs to be implemented without the assumption that hasNext has been called beforehand.

Let's imagine we have the following situation:

```
final Iterator<String> bogusIt01 = new Iterator<String>() {

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    public String next() {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("no such element");
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cannot remove element");
    }

};

final Iterable<String> bogusPr01 = new Iterable<String>() {

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return bogusIt01;
    }

};

for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") String string:bogusPr01) {
    // pass
}
```

This will raise NoSuchElementException. I would expect for the loop to just terminate. Am I doing it wrong?

The reason I am asking is because by using this model it is very difficult to write an iterator that wraps around another iterator and does some processing on its output. Let's imagine the following scenario:

Iterator1 <- this is our original iterator and it is all fine.

Iterator2 <- this iterator wraps around Iterator1 and modifies the output of the iterated elements.

Iterator2 is implemented like this:

```
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterator1.hasNext();
    }

    public Object next() {
        if (!iterator1.hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("no such element");
        }

        Object nextValue = iterator1.next();

        try {
            // do something that could raise exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return this.next();
        }

        return productValue;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cannot remove element");
    }
```

Such a design is simply not possible although it makes a lot of sense to me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code is that an `Iterator` should NEVER throw a `NoSuchElementException` from `getNext` if the previous call to `hasNext` returned true. You might consider doing something like this:

1. in `hasNext` get the next appropriate element from the underlying iterator and cache it until the next call to `next`. From `next` just return the cached value. If the cached value is null then `hasNext` was not called and you can then appropriately throw NSEE.

The other option you might want to consider is using Guava's `Iterables.transform` or `Lists.transform`. This is designed to take a `Iterable` and perform some translation on each element. You could return `null` for any value that could not be transformed and do a `Iterables.filter` using the `Predicates.notNull` `Predicate` to remove elements that were not null.

[Iterables.transform](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-)

[Iterables.filter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Predicate-)

[Predicates.notNull](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#notNull--)

Using Guava, the above code would be :

```
Function<A, B> myFunction = new Function<A,B>(){
   public B apply(A input){
      try{ // do work
         return new B();
      catch(Exception e){ return null; }          
   }
}

Iterable<A> inputList = ...;
Iterable<B> newList = Iterables.filter(
       Iterables.transform(inputList, myFunction), 
       Predicates.notNull());

for (B b : newList)...
```

Comment: This is what I used to do but this sounds like such a a bad design. The method hasNext should never perform any work apart from indicating if there are more items. The method next should do the work. I am surprised that NoSuchElementException is not the equivalent of break; in foreach loops. Otherwise, what is the point? I could as well raise any other RuntimeException and the effect will be the same.

Comment: As Peter states, throwing a NoSuchElementException after `hasNext` returns true does not match the API. Java does not try to figure out why objects do not match the API, it just let's the coder figure that out. If you want to use Java's inherent structures (list for each) you MUST match the API.

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc for [Iterator.hasNext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

> Returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns true if next() would return an element rather than throwing an exception.)

In general, the JVM will not try to second guess what it should do, or perform a workaround, if you fail to conform to the API as specified. Instead it will produce the exception or error you get.

If you are wrapping an iterator which could cause an exception, you should either throw that exception or if you feel it is better to pretend it never happened (which is unlikely IMHO) you have to check this before calling next().

```
Object productValue = null;
public boolean hasNext() {
    produceValue = null;
    while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
        Object nextValue = iterator1.next();

        try {
            // do something that could raise exception
            produceValue = ....
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle the exception.
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public Object next() {
    if (produceValue == null && !hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException("no such element");
    Object ret = productValue;
    productValue = null;
    return ret;
}

public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cannot remove element");
}
```

Comment: This is great but also a bit backwards design. How can you recover from a situation where true is returned in hasNext but next blows up because it cannot perform the job? I understand if an exception is propagated if different than NoSuchElementException but NoSuchElementException should really be considered as break; No?

Comment: You cannot return `true` until you know `next()` has an object to return. See the example above.

Comment: FYI, in the example above if `produceValue` is `null`, `hasNext` should be called from `next` before throwing the exception. It should be possible to call `next` n times to get the first n elements without resulting in an exception if the iterable contains at least n elements.

Comment: I have changed it so next() can be called without calling hasNext() each time.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class BreakingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private Iterator<T> iterator;
    private T nextValue;
    private RuntimeException nextException;

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    public BreakingIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        this.nextValue = null;
        this.nextException = null;
    }

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (this.iterator.hasNext()) {
            try {
                this.nextValue = this.iterator.next();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                this.nextValue = null;
                this.nextException = e;

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public T next() {
        if (this.nextException != null) {
            throw this.nextException;
        } else {
            return this.nextValue;
        }
    }

    public void remove() {
        this.iterator.remove();
    }

}
```

This implementation will move all the hard work from next into hasNext.

Comment: How is this different from the other two answers that were posted? If you notice, when I suggest this in my answer the OP stated that doing the work in `hasNext` was not acceptable. You also fell into the same trap that Peter did in his answer, not calling `hasNext` from `next` in case `hasNext` was not called.

Comment: This solution is kind of workaround for those who think the right way is the one I illustrated. In other words, if you wrap this inner Iterator with the BreakingIterator the whole thing will work fine in the above example.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize you answered your own question. Generally it is not a good idea to post a "possible solution" as an answer. If you found the answer and know it works, great post it as an answer. Otherwise, if you think you have a possible solution add it to your question. That said, if you are OK with doing the work in `hashNext` instead of `next` and you fix the issue of not calling `hasNext` from `next` when `nextValue` is null, yes this will work.

Comment: However, the solution is different than your original post in that your original post ate the exception and just tried to return the next element where this solution throws the exception. Which is correct depends on your requirements. I would again consider looking at the Guava solution as I think it is cleaner.

Comment: WRT your comment, actually not really. If you have an iterator with more than n elements, you can call `next` n times and get the first n elements without ever calling `hasNext`. Your solution returns `null`.

Comment: I've polished to solution slightly to mitigate this. Given your comments above I do not know now how to post it. :)